# How to enable speech input in kendo ui control chatbot using direcline?

Tags: kendo-ui, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I want to add voice option in kendo UI chatbot. I am able to achieve it by using webchat but how to do the same in kendo?

Below is the code by which I am able to get the speech option in webchat.
[Speech option enabled code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO5Ny.png)
I want to achieve something like that.
[Speech in botchat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsq4p.png)

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.chat = $("#BotChatGoesHere").kendoChat({
        post: function (args) {
            agent.postMessage(args);
        },
    }).data("kendoChat");
    var agent = new DirectLineAgent(window.chat, "token");
});
const speechOptions = {
    speechRecognizer: new KendoChat.Speech.BrowserSpeechRecognizer(),
    speechSynthesizer: new KendoChat.Speech.BrowserSpeechSynthesizer()
};
var AdaptiveCardComponent = kendo.chat.Component.extend({
    init: function (options, view) {
        kendo.chat.Component.fn.init.call(this, options, view);
        var adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
        adaptiveCard.hostConfig = new AdaptiveCards.HostConfig({
            fontFamily: "Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
        });
        adaptiveCard.parse(options);
        var bodyElement = $("<div'>").addClass("k-card-body").append(adaptiveCard.render());
        this.element.addClass("k-card").append(bodyElement);
    }
});

kendo.chat.registerComponent("application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive", AdaptiveCardComponent);
window.DirectLineAgent = kendo.Class.extend({
    init: function (chat, secret) {
        this.speechOptions = speechOptions;
        this.chat = chat;
        this.iconUrl = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/v4sdk/media/logo_bot.svg?view=azure-bot-service-4.0";
        this.agent = new DirectLine.DirectLine({ secret: secret });
        this.agent.activity$.subscribe($.proxy(this.onResponse, this));
    },
    postMessage: function (args) {
        var postArgs = {
            text: args.text,
            type: args.type,
            timestamp: args.timestamp,
            from: args.from
        };

        this.agent.postActivity(postArgs)
            .subscribe();
    },
    onResponse: function (response) {
        if (response.from.id === this.chat.getUser().id) {
            return;
        }
        response.from.iconUrl = this.iconUrl;
        this.renderMessage(response);
        this.renderAttachments(response);
        this.renderSuggestedActions(response.suggestedActions);
    },

    renderMessage: function (message) {
        if (message.text || message.type == "typing") {
            this.chat.renderMessage(message, message.from);
        }
    },
    renderAttachments: function (data) {
        this.chat.renderAttachments(data, data.from);
    },
    renderSuggestedActions: function (suggestedActions) {
        var actions = [];
        if (suggestedActions && suggestedActions.actions) {
            actions = suggestedActions.actions;
        }
        this.chat.renderSuggestedActions(actions);
    },
});
```

Comment: To clarify, you don't want to use web chat but are wanting to use direct line? And, in addition, want speech to be enabled using direct line?

Comment: Also, can you please post the code you have tried?

Comment: Yes I don't want to use webchat because I am using kendochat and I am using direcline but speech option is not visible in kendo UI chatbot.

Comment: I posted the code,

Comment: Steven Kanberg  could you please check the above code and do let me know how can I add the speech option inside kendo UI with jquery. In webchat  it is easy to enable speech option but in kenod UI how to enable.

Comment: Do you need more clarity?

Comment: Direct Line doesn't enable speech in Web Chat. That is a feature of Web Chat, itself, and the browser. Web Chat merely makes use of DL for connecting to the bot. The most DL does is read an activity to see if the `speak` property has been assigned (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/blob/0f32a7c09a19ce637857e746613ce26ef3d8ca79/src/directLine.ts#L310)). Unfortunately, I have no experience with Kendo, so I am unable to provide much beyond this.